# download pdf file of blade instead of view in browser

Tags: pdf, download, dompdf

I would like the browser to download file on button click of blade page. The following is used in controller and and added in provider file, but its showing in browser console but not downloading file.

```
use PDF;

// this controller 
function sensorChartPDF(){

     $pdf = PDF::loadView('sensorchartpdf');

    return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf')->header('Content-Type','application/pdf');;

    }
```

///// sensorchartpdf.blade.php  this is view ///
https://canvasjs.com/javascript-charts/multi-series-spline-chart/

chart static code appened in this file

Answer (score 0):

To signify to the web browser that the file should be downloaded and not displayed in line you have to specify the content-disposition header with a value of attachment.

Your question, however, does not appear to be purely a question regarding Dompdf. With Dompdf you would merely use the following:

```
$dompdf->stream("output.pdf", array('Attachment' => 1));
```

I'm providing this for anyone looking for similar issue when working with the library directly.

Since you're not using Dompdf directly but via another library so you'll need to specify exactly which library or framework you're using before somebody can provide an accurate answer.